# An assembly print buffer

Tags: assembly, printing, null, buffer, 6502

I'm doing it again but I'm close this time. Working with a  6502 chip.

I am writing a program of an assembly print buffer.

The one problem I'm having is checking if the string is null.

Here is my code so far: (human readable)

```
buffer = $03ff
x = $01

[START]: $0500

    LDX buffer      // load buffer (at safe memory address $03ff)
    LDY #$00        // loading the y register with 0 so that you can count up
                // checking for a null string; if null, branch to the break instruction
LOOP:   LDA buffer+1, y     // get byte using the buffer
    STA (x), y  // store the value at the pointer
    INY         // increment y
    DEX         // decrement x (counting down with the x register)
    BEQ $500?       // if x is equal to 0, program is done
    BNE LOOP:       // if x is not equal to 0, keep going
    BRK             // if brk, it’s null
```

How would I go about checking if the string is null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just do an explicit test for zero first:

```
[START]: $0500

    LDY #$00
    LDX buffer

    BEQ ENDOFLOOP

LOOP:  
    LDA buffer+1, y
    STA (x), y
    INY
    DEX

    BNE LOOP

ENDOFLOOP:
    BRK
```

`LDX` sets the zero flag so there's no need to do anything to `X` before the test.

Comment: thanks ill try this! so SUPER SUPER (2 day to be exact) newbie question for assembly...but I'm confused on the syntax of BEQ.

Comment: In the assembler, do I put BEQ ENDOFLOOP (I'm confused on what memory address...do I just count how many lines I will input and put that memory address?

Comment: If you were writing actual machine code, the jump would be the count in bytes from where the PC is when it makes the decision to where it should end up but you don't have to worry about it with an assembler — the exact syntax varies a little but normally something like `LOOP:` will be taken by the assembler to be a label and `BNE LOOP` will mean `BNE` to wherever that label is; the assembler will calculate the correct number of bytes and fill it in for you.

Comment: Does it tell you where? Different assemblers don't exactly agree, especially on labels and, if your assembler is really old, whether you have to do anything special for jumping to labels that are defined later in the file rather than earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just move the comparison to the front...

```
    ...
    LDY #$00
LOOP:
    LDA buffer+1, y
    BEQ ENDOFLOOP:
    STA (x), y
    INY
    DEX
    JMP LOOP:
ENDOFLOOP:
    ...
```

My 6502 is really rusty, but you get the idea.

Comment: What about a null string case though?

Comment: How are you defining a null string?  Are you referring to where the head of the buffer is null, or the buffer address is $0000?

Comment: I'm using the PASCAL definition for a string. I'm referring to where the head of the buffer is null